# Precice delivery of implicit Intents

Tags: android, security, android-intent

I currently have the situation where I need to be able to launch application A through a implicit Intent broadcast from application B. No data is being delivered between the applications. Application A is simply launched, displaying a certain Activity.

My question is thus; Is it possible from the stand point of the Android SDK to make sure that when application B broadcasts a Intent using a specific scheme (i.e test://something ) that it only goes to application A, even if there is a application C that has registered the same scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: Use `setPackage()` on the `Intent`, providing the application ID of Application A

Option #2: Use `queryBroadcastReceivers()` on the `Intent`, sift through the results, find the one for Application A, and use that information to craft an explicit `Intent`, which is what you broadcast

Comment: Ah I had forgotten setPackage() in the Intent API. Thank you for pointing it out to me.